# are qqplots appropriate for time series?

Tags: time-series, qq-plot

I've seen that qqplots are a very useful tool to check model assumptions. In particular to analyze the residuals. However, it seems that is based on data ordering and therefore assumes a atationary distribution. When the data are time series (other than the residuals) the data ordering is probably not appropriated since the distribution of the data may be time-varying. It is not clear to me whether a qqplot on a time series would provide useful information and if alternative methods are available.

EDIT: Assume a standard gaussian linear state space model with one covariate and no intercept. We would expect all distributions to be gaussian. We find the residuals are not gaussian. I would like to know what's causing the non-gaussianity of residuals $\nu_t=y_t-\beta_tx_t$. It might be $\epsilon_t$ in the measurement equation $y_t=\beta_tx_t+\epsilon_t$, it might be $\eta_t$ in the system equation $\beta_t=\beta_{t-1}+\eta_t$ or maybe the covariate?. Is there any way of checking which one is causing non-gaussianity so I can improve my model?

Comment: This question is still pretty confusing.  I'm not sure what you mean by the ordering of the QQ plot.  The data in the QQ plot are ordered, which makes sense because they are quantiles.  But the ordering should not be related to the index of the time series.  However if you are worried about the stationarity then plot the ACF of the residuals.  I don't understand the edit portion, the finite sum of normal R.V.s are normal, so if they aren't normal then your assumption was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If a series isn't stationary, then

1. your values don't all come from the same distribution, so how would ignoring that and looking at the marginal distribution be informative?
2. what assumption would relate to such a calculation?

Comment: thank you this is what I expected. Is there any feasible alternative to check?

Comment: To check *what* exactly?

Comment: I believe my question is clear enough since I'm taking about checking the form of the distribution we have assumed for a time series. I'll edit my post with an example.

Comment: @Glen_b I think all he wants is a (graphical) way to check if the series is stationary. Think of a residual plot to check on normality assumption forma linear regression. Sorry AP13, can't help con time series.

Comment: @mugen While you may be right, that's not how I interpret the modified question.